# create a read more link for post and archives

Tags: read-more

I am building a custom theme. But my theme doesn't have read more button below posts. i don't know how to do that.

Can anyone please tell me how to get the read more link below the posts with excerpt length.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The docs have a page about h[ow to create read more links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Basic way:

```
the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser );
```